# Can different Kickstarter accounts use the same credit card to pay for the same project?

Tags: kickstarter

A friend wants to back a Kickstarter project, but she has no credit card. I would let her use my credit card, but I’m backing the same project already.

Is it possible to have two **different accounts** (with different email and postal addresses) that back the ***same* project**, and both accounts use the **same credit card**?

I would simply try it, but what stops me is the possibility that one of the pledges might get canceled when the project ends (i.e., when they try to get the money).

Answer (score 2):

The Kickstarter support answered that **it’s possible**.

My friend has to enter my billing address for that. Kickstarter itself never asks for the shipping address, so she can enter her own address when the project owner asks for it.

She tried and it worked, as expected, without any error messages (but the project is still running; I’ll update should anything happen).